# Python regex lookahead with 2 negative conditions

Tags: python, regex, boolean-logic, regex-lookarounds

In Python, I am having trouble with a regex which has 2 negative conditions in the lookahead.  This seems like it should be easy, but somehow I'm not seeing the solution after several attempts...

I have large blocks of text that can include:

beneficiary

beneficiary acct

beneficiary bank

What I want is:

beneficiary name

beneficiary account

beneficiary bank

I don't want to erroneously change

beneficiary to beneficiary name

as that could lead to

beneficiary name acct

beneficiary name bank

That is, I want to change

"beneficiary" to "beneficiary name"

if and only if
"beneficiary" isn't followed by "acct" 
AND
"beneficiary" isn't followed by "bank"

But how can I test both lookaheads with an AND to ensure both conditions are met?

In regex, I am only seeing the OR - like this:
bene_lookahead_or = r'beneficiary\s?(?!acct) | beneficiary\s?(?!bank)'

Is there a Python regex AND?
If not, is there a Python regex way to negate?
That is, negate the OR like a Boolean Algebra NOR
such as
change beneficiary to beneficiary name
if not
(
beneficiary is followed by acct 
or 
beneficiary is followed by bank
)

I'm obviously missing something here...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *NOR's* inside negative anything, like *classes* or assertions,
automatically negate each item and are *ANDed* together.

In your example it would be this usage `beneficiary(?![ ](?:acct|account|bank))`

Expanded

```
 beneficiary
 (?!                           # Negative assertion
      [ ]                           # Space
      (?:                           # Not any of these
           acct
        |  account                       
        |  bank 
      )
 )
```

Comment: sin: Thank you - this helped me resolve my issue.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @sm_ninja - No problem. If any answers helped solve your problem you can upvote them and/or mark them solved if it did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an alternation where the last alternative is an empty string and do it in one pass:

```
s = '''beneficiary

beneficiary acct

beneficiary bank'''

pat = re.compile(r'\bbeneficiary( acct| bank|)\b')
rep = { ' acct':' account', ' bank':' bank' }

result = pat.sub(lambda m: 'beneficiary{0}'.format(rep[m.group(1)]) if m.group(1) else 'beneficiary name', s)
```

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte:  Thank you for your feedback.  I see some code here I can learn from which is always welcomed.  Also, it helped me realize I hadn't explained my issue clearly - something for me to consider nexttime...  I might have "beneficiary {various text items here...}.  {some more various text} beneficiary account {more text}... ... beneficiary bank {more text}...  and that some or all or none of them will be present and in no particular order.